# EKS Cluster endpoint access

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-eks

i am a bit confused about EKS Cluster end point access and EKS Private cluster. EKS Private cluster needs to have ECR as container registry. but if i keep EKS Cluster endpoint as private, does that means its a private cluster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The EKS cluster endpoint is orthogonal to the way you configure the networking for your workloads. Usually an EKS Private cluster is a cluster WHOSE NODES AND WORKLOADS do not have outbound access to the internet (commonly used by big enterprises with hybrid connectivity so that the data flow only travels within a private network (i.e. VPC and on-prem). The endpoint is where your `kubectl` points to and it's different. It could be public, private or both at the same time. In most cases if you want an EKS Private cluster is likely that you want the endpoint to be private as well but it's just an obvious choice not a technical requirement.